# refile a table row in emacs org mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have a template for org-capture more that looks like:

```
("w" "Websites" table-line (file+olp "~/Dropbox/mystuff.org" "Websites" "To view")
 "| %c | %^{Description}")
```

which adds a table line to a table of web pages I want to view when I do org-capture and press 'w'.

This works just fine. The I wanted to refile the To View table line to a table with the headline "Viewed" using this

```
(setq org-refile-targets '(("mystuff.org" :regexp . "Viewed")
```

But what org mode does is takes the whole table rather than the url on the row I want to refile, and puts the To View table under the Viewed table. Obviously not what I want. Is there a way to do what I want?